# How To Import Data From Module into a Custom HTML Module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

if you take a look at my website: [NerdyFuture](http://nerdyfuture.byethost24.com). You can probably see the couple of pictures at the top of the website. I made this in a custom HTML module, now what I want to achieve is to input data from another module in the custom HTML module I made. I want input the data from the module: Mini Frontpage. So the data that I need from Mini Frontpage is the title,thumbnail,description and link from one article. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can simply load module 1 into module 2.

In your Custom HTML module, add the following into the textarea:

```
{loadposition XXX}
```

Where `XXX` is the position of your first module.

To load an article into your Custom HTML module, you can also use NoNumber's [Articles Anywhere](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/articlesanywhere) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to load a module from your custom HTML extension would be to include the following code:

```
echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{loadposition someposition}');
```

Here you can read in more detail: https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla-how-to/module-position-component/